# MySql - get summary with date of the last 'DatumÄ

Tags: mysql, database

following problem:
Table with 'Datum' and 'Tagesertrag_kWh' like

| Datum | Tagesertrag_kWh |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 11.267 |
| 2022-05-02 | 20.475 |
| 2022-05-03 | 19.937 |

Now I want have the sum of 'Tagesertrag_kWh' with the last 'Datum' like

| Datum | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-03 | value |

I tried following

```
select Datum, 
       sum(Tagesertrag_kWh) sum 
FROM solar.monthly 
where Datum like '2022-05-%';"
```

but I got only the first date, like

| Datum | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | value |

How can I ask and get the last 'Datum' ?

Hopefully the problem is seen ?
regards
waldo

Comment: Please read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What about: `select MAX(Datum) datum, sum(Tagesertrag_kWh) sum FROM.....`  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have and the latest date and the SUM of all values in `Tagesertrag_kWh` column, then use something like:

```
select Datum, sum(Tagesertrag_kWh) sum 
FROM solar.monthly 
order by Datum desc 
limit 1;
```

Additionally, use appropriate datatype while defining the date related fields more info about such fields: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: this works  "select MAX(Datum) datum, sum(Tagesertrag_kWh) sum FROM solar.monthly where Datum like '2022-05-%'"      thanks a lot